# Save and load browser history for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, browser-history

Using Selenium Webdriver for Python, is it possible to save the browser history of a session and reload the history in a future session?  I know cookies can be saved and reloaded if they match the current domain but I'm trying to test websites with different types of profiles.  Thanks.

Comment: I see that best aproach is to save directed links dynamicaly otherwise you can try save driver variable using pickle module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not so much you can do about it. First of all, selenium webdriver API provides you with just `forward()` and `back()` methods for navigating the history ([documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#navigation-history-and-location)).

The DOM `window` object could have helped you since it provides access to the [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.history) object, but due to security reasons: [you cannot push history items from outside of domain of the current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079704/javascript-history-pushstate-not-working).

Also see:

- [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

But, if all of your URLs are within the same domain, you can get use of `history.pushState()` method, example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver


WIKI_PAGE = 'How_I_Met_Your_Mother'

driver = webdriver.WebDriver()
driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki')

script = 'history.pushState({}, "", "%s")' % WIKI_PAGE
driver.execute_script(script)

driver.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki')
```

Here, wikipedia main page is opened in Firefox browser, then a history item is inserted, then the main page is opened again. If you'll click `Back` in the browser window, you'll get "How I met your mother" wikipedia page.

Hope that helps.