# How to make browser history persistent when using selenium for automated browsing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium 4 in python and for webdriver of the respective browser I am using [webdriver_manger](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#use-with-chrome) which automatically downloads the correct webdriver. 
I want that browsing history during a selenium automation session to remain persistent even after the driver exits.
After some research I found out that you need to attach a existing profile to the webdirver [from the answer on this questi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66362407/keeping-a-persistent-browser-history-on-selenium) , which also doesn't seem to be working. 
 It could be because selenium copies the profile into a temporary location and uses it from there so original profile doesn't get corrupted. 
 So is there a way you can make the history persistent that even after closing the driver the history can be seen when you manually open the browser later.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service as EdgeService
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
import time

edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

edge_options.use_chromium = True

edge_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\abdul\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data\\Default")

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=edge_options)

driver.get("https://adobe.com")

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

I want the visit to https://adobe.com to stay persistent in the profile even after the driver has exited.
And is there a way I can find out where selenium copies the profile temporarily so maybe I can save it?
Thank you.