# Is there a way to access the WebExtension's history to access browser history (not session history)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414735/save-and-load-browser-history-for-selenium) question which navigates the session history. It links to the WebExtension history object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history). I was wondering how one uses this to get a list of history items in Python.

The following code gives me an error that search is not found in the history object despite the documentation saying it is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
    
    
driver = webdriver.WebDriver()
script = 'history.search({})'
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: that's for browser extensions/plugins...  you can't call it from client-side JS and you'd need the extension that uses the API to be installed.  The only client-side methods you can use are  window.history.back() and window.history.forward()