# How to use shortcuts with RSelenium

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox, rselenium

How are shortcuts used in RSelenium?

In the example below, I use a common shortcut to display the browsing history in Firefox. That is: push and hold Control key + press H key.

While the shortcut works just fine if one presses the keys manually, it does not work when done with Rselenium. Anyone?

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox") 

remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")

remDr$navigate("https://www.amazon.com")

elem <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//body")
elem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = 'control',  'H'))

#here is another example with three keys. 
#the reload shortcut control+shift+R
elem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = 'control',  key = 'shift','R'))

#it is very intriguing that the select all shortcut, control + a, works well.
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "control", "a"))
```

Comment: I think you can't do that.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419815/2554330 for the history in particular; for other shortcuts, I think you would need to do something similar, i.e. implement whatever the shortcut does using Javascript or other Selenium commands.

Comment: Selenium is limited to the DOM.  So is javascript.  You have no access to browser window shortcuts/commands.   (You'd need a robot-type class to do this... or possibly some kind of browser launch flag/preference set in options )

Comment: What is weird is that the shortcut "control" + "a" works.

Comment: yeah, so does ctrl-v.  I think ctrl-t and ctrl-tab used to work, too... (they might have removed those)