# Unable to generate links using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the code of my "app.js" :

```
 var app = angular.module('WebUI',[]);

app.config(function($httpProvider){
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
});

app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Here is the code of my controller :

```
    var Controller = function ($scope,$http)
    {
    $scope.thingsList=[];
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://192.168.1.4/search'}).success(function(data)
    {
        results=data.results;
        angular.forEach(results,function(result)
        {
            $scope.thingsList.push(result.split('/')[1]);
        });     
    }).error(function(data){});
    }
```

Here is the code of my HTML page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>All</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
    <div id='content' ng-app='WebUI' ng-controller='Controller'>
        <li ng-repeat="thing in thingsList">
        <a href="home.html">{{thing}}</a>
        </li>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The point here is that I am generating the links using ng-repeat and the list that I get from my controller.js. But what happens is that : When I click "HOME" it gets redirects to the home page and when I click any of the "thing" i.e. generated link, then it throws an error :

```
Error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///home/abc/home.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
```

I tried searching online for this error but could not find anything useful. So if anybody knows where the problem is, please help :)

Comment: can  you create a plunker?

Comment: The application is huge, so unfortunately can't.Actually this problem is only with one page...on the previous page, it works fine :(

Comment: Here is the reason to the problem you are facing http://stackoverflow.com/a/20079760/1690339

Comment: Yeah, but didn't understand it in my case :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found the answer to my own question.
I searched online and found that generating too many `"file:///"` links cause a security issue that's why they are not allowed.

Then I tried hosting it on a server `http://` and testing, then the URL changed, but the page was not refreshed...so again error.

Then I found out that

```
 `app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});`
```

This portion of code was throwing errors due to which I was unable to use `ng-route` and other things.

But location needed this code to parse the get parameters in the URL, so I took reference from [What's the most concise way to read query parameters in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063673/whats-the-most-concise-way-to-read-query-parameters-in-angularjs) and I was able to pass the get parameters in the URL using another way like : `url#/?target=bob` and I was able to parse the parameters now.

So problem solved. `$location` was able to parse the parameters and I was also now able to access the links which earlier gave error.

Answer (score 2):

```
A history state object with URL 'file:///home/abc/home.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
```

Seems you're using angular routing on file urls, and without a server.

Try with a server.

Comment: Tried with a server, it freezes...i.e. the URL changes but doesn't redirect to the page.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ng-href`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window location:

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in thingsList">
    <a ng-click="gotoHome()">{{thing}}</a>
</li>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.gotoHome = function(){
  window.location="#/home";

                //Give your link above.
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I tried this way, but didn't work. But anyways found the problem :)