# Google chrome gives an error about replaceState, how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Here's the error shown at the google chrome console

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history >state object with URL cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.

This only happens when I run my HTML file with google chrome, it works with every other browser I have in my computer.

I have jquery and jquery-mobile 1.4.5 as my scripts. And the error occurs in the jquery-mobile 1.4.5

Can anybody help?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I don't have any self-made JS, I just used the jquery-mobile as a plugin. 
And that this error only started happening after google chrome's version 45 update

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723654/replacestate-a-history-state-with-url-cannot-be-created-in-a-document-wit

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I think. My html runs perfectly fine before the new update of google chrome. I hope anybody can help

Comment: are you loading the html as a file:/// or http:// (or https://)

Comment: in other words ... `A history state object with URL` _what did you remove from here_ `cannot be created`

Comment: someone else just got the same issue ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439759/new-update-of-jquery-mobile-needs-a-web-server-to-run ... the problem seems to be with file:/// urls ... which is one of the comments made in the possible duplicate ...

Comment: sorry, I load the html as file:///

Comment: in that case it's a known "issue" (if you could call it an issue)

Comment: I didn't say it was a chrome issue