# New update of jQuery mobile needs a web server to run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Since less than a week ago jQuery Mobile made an automatic update that made it very difficult to debug without using a web server to run the application. To code I used to only open the .html file in the web browser as a simple document and I could debug, but now I need to run it in a web server to make it work, it keeps sending this message when I open it as a simple file:

***Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/LL402/Desktop/index.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.***

Does someone know how to fix this? I hate using a server to test a simple web application.

Comment: It's a Chrome 45 issue according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439224/google-chrome-gives-an-error-about-replacestate-how-do-i-fix-this - use a different (better) browser

Comment: Install a simple local web server (`php -S localhost:8080` will do the job). There are so many things that work differently between local files and HTTP in browsers that it doesn't make sense to develop without one.

Comment: `I hate using a server to test a simple web application.` a note on this. Browsers very often behave differently depending on the protocol used. If you're testing a web app, why would you test it using file:/// protocol? It's a small sacrifice to make

Comment: Because sometimes I need to debug during my classes or in random computers (Because lack of time). That's one of the things I liked about jQuery mobile.

Comment: The first comment is right, its a Google chrome issue. I've just tested it in mozilla and it works fine there. I'll change the web browser to debug

Comment: Using a server (also easy to start using `python -m`) always has a few advantages. ajax wont always work as expecting on the `file://` protocol. Also, running on a server is closer to a productive environment

Comment: What about mobile hybrid applications(Phonegap)?