# Hiding some characters in URL bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, url

I have my URL like 
www.abc.com/some_folder1/some_folder2/page.php 
is there are any ways to hide "some_folder1 or 2" In URL while it is displaying on URL bar like :

```
www.abc.com/some_folder1/page.php
```

or

```
www.abc.com/some_folder2/page.php
```

(have to just hide "by keeping its functionalities unaffected")

Comment: This modification can be made using `.htaccess` or `web.config`. I don't think it can be made using jQuery

Comment: you may be able to do that only by caching that folder in localStorage and then redirect to the desired page, but that will still be visible for the first time to the user

Comment: Thank you @MarioRawady. how can we do this using .htaccess ?

Comment: Are you looking to hide the path dynamically: `The folder name differs from scenario to scenario` or is it a predefined path that is not changeable?

Comment: No, it is not happening dynamically, It is a predefined path. I tried something like this in javascript, "window.location = window.location.href.replace('/some_folder1', ' ' );". but it is removing "some_folder1" and when I try to access the file I get, page not found.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 

console.log( window.location.href );  
window.history.replaceState( {} ,window.location.href.toString().replace( "/some_folder2","" ), window.location.href.toString() );
console.log( window.location.href );
```

> This code will hide the text in URL in the browser address bar. **It works for HTML5 enabled browsers**.

Please take a look at this discussion for more details : 
[history.replaceState() example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832317/history-replacestate-example)

Comment: Thank you @RameshRajendran. but it will remove "some_folder2" and replaces with " ". and we will get, page not found error. I just want to hide it without affecting the functionalities.

Comment: Take  a look at this discussion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723654/replacestate-a-history-state-with-url-cannot-be-created-in-a-document-wit