# History pushState throws Uncaught DOMException

Tags: javascript, api, history.js

So I am using the History API and I am trying to use the pushState() function :

`I did this:
history.pushState({'a': 'b'}, 'Document', "index2.html");`

It gives me this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL '...' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL '...'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it this issue?
[replaceState() with document origin null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723654/replacestate-a-history-state-with-url-cannot-be-created-in-a-document-wit/32171354#32171354)

If so, the answer there indicates that this works:

```
history.replaceState(null,null, window.location.pathname + "your thing here");
```

Comment: Yes, this was it, thank you for the answer.