# history.pushState error,i dont know why

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var oInput = document.getElementById('input1');
            var oDiv = document.getElementById('div1');
            var iNow = 1;
            oInput.onclick = function(){
                var number = randomNum(35,7);
                oDiv.innerHTML = number;
                history.pushState(number,'');

            }
            window.onpopstate = function(event){
                var number = event.state || '';
                oDiv.innerHTML = number;
            }

            function randomNum(alls,now){
                var arr = [];
                var newArr = [];
                for(var i=1;i<=alls;i++){
                    arr.push(i);
                }

                for(var i=0;i<now;i++){
                    newArr.push(arr.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length),1));
                }
                return newArr;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button"  id="input1" value="35選7" />
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
```

I don't know why `history.pushState` does not work, it throws the error:

```
history.html:14 Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on   

'History': A history state object with URL  
'file:///C:/Users/TED/Documents/HBuilderProjects/javascript-%E7%9F%A5%E8%AD%98%E9%A1%9E/history.html' cannot be created in a document 
with origin 'null' and URL 
'file:///C:/Users/TED/Documents/HBuilderProjects/javascript-%E7%9F%A5%E8%AD%98%E9%A1%9E/history.html'.oInput.onclick @ history.html:14
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript history.PushState not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079704/javascript-history-pushstate-not-working)

Comment: @mevius this isn't about calling pustState wrong, but using `file:///` and expecting web behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

Don't pretend that `file:///` is the same as "web pages": they didn't get loaded by the browser using the same mechanism that real web pages go through, and lots of things that web pages can do will not work for "plain files".

If you want to see how your code behaves as web page, using web APIs, then you'll need to load it properly using `http(s)`. That means using a simple server (not even a full blow Apache or the like, just a one-liner http server like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, or [`php -S localhost:8000`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) or node.js's [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or [`live-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) packages, etc. etc.) and then load it through http://localhost:someport/yourfilename, where "someport" is whatever port number the one-line server says is being used, and "yourfilename" is obviously the name of your file.

Comment: so now i just need to simulate on web page, and it is ok right?

Comment: not "simulate": all the solutions listed are real web page serving solutions. And yes, each of them solves the CORS origin problem you get when you use `file:///`

Comment: not sure who decided to throw two downvotes at this answer on the same day 4 years after the fact, but this answer is 100% applicable to the problem. When using `file:///`, almost nothing about normal browser behaviour applies, due to an incredibly more restricted security model.